# pyCharm does not find library file in django program

Tags: django, django-templates, pycharm

In a Django programm pyCharm (prof.) highlights `utils_modal` in a %load% statement with the info "unresolved library 'utils_modal'".

My Django program has this structure

```
djProgram
 |
 +-+- app_1
 | +-- __init__.py
 | +-- templates
 |   +-- app_1
 |     +-- template.html
 |
 +-+- app_2
 | +-- __init__.py
 ...
 +-- utils
   +-- templatetags
     +- utils_modal.py
```

`utils` is a non app folder, just a library for some modals used in the apps. This folder is mentioned in `settings.py` in the `TEMPLATES` structure:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates') ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # some definitions
            ],
            'libraries': {
                'utils_modal': 'utils.templatetags.utils_modal',
            },
        },
    },
]
```

`template.html` starts like this:

```
{% extends 'users/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load utils_modal %} {# <-- Here is the pyCharm warning "Unresolved library 'utils_modal'" #}

{% block content %}
    <!-- HTML code -->
{% endblock %}
```

What mistake have I made here? Thanks in advance.

I am working with Windows 11, pyCharm professional 2023.3.2, Django 4.2.7